# php header location not redirecting page

Tags: php, session, redirect

I have following code in the start of my php file but somehow it doesnt redirect to login page, however if I separate if condition into sub if condition then redirection works
**Below code doesnt work**

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['emailid'], $_SESSION['roleid']) && $_SESSION['roleid'] != 1) {
  header('location:login.php?lmsg=true');
  exit;
}
///This doesnt work
```

**Below code work**

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['emailid'], $_SESSION['roleid'])) {
  header('location:login.php?lmsg=true');
  exit();
}
if ($_SESSION['roleid'] != 1) {
  header('location:login.php?lmsg=true');
  exit();
}
///this works
```

can someone help?

Comment: You want "OR", not "AND". All conditions must be met.

Comment: Thanks.it worked with OR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easier to read and it's probably want you meant to do:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['emailid'], $_SESSION['roleid']) or (isset($_SESSION['roleid']) and $_SESSION['roleid'] != 1)) {
    header('location:login.php?lmsg=true');
    exit;
}
```